# WP7 Timer CallBack is not fired during User Activity

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, timer, mvvm-light

I have page which is desgined for map point browsing. I want to show a Border to user. this border contains informations for User (it is somethink like messagebox).

I use MVVM patern...

I want to hide the border after 3 seconds. Everything works (border is hidden after 3 seconds) until I start to move with the map control. Then the border will never hide.

Attached code will explain more...

Part of my XAML code from the View:

```
<Grid>
<my:Map 
    Margin="0,0,0,0" 
    x:Name="MainMap" 
    CredentialsProvider="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    Center="{Binding MapCenter, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ZoomLevel="{Binding ZoomLevel, Mode=TwoWay}"                     
    myMapViewModel:BindingHelpers.TileSource="{Binding CurrentMap}" 
    myMapViewModel:BindingHelpers.PointsSource="{Binding Points}"
            myMapViewModel:BindingHelpers.CurrentPositionPushpin="{Binding CurrentGeoPosition}"
    myMapViewModel:BindingHelpers.KmlPointSelectedCommand="{Binding ShowSelectedKmlPointCommand}"
    Grid.Row="0"
    CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed"
    ZoomBarVisibility="Collapsed"  
            Padding="0"
    >

    <my:Map.Mode>
        <MSPCMCore:MercatorMode/>
    </my:Map.Mode>

    <TextBlock 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        x:Name="MapNameTile" 
        Text="{Binding CurrentMapName}" 
        Opacity="0.5" 
        Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"                    
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Canvas.ZIndex="2"
                    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"

                    />
</my:Map>

<Border 
        Canvas.ZIndex="20"                        
        Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" 
        Opacity="0.85"
        Height="100"
        Width="430"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        CornerRadius="15"
        Padding="15"
        Margin="0,25,0,0"
        Visibility="{Binding IsInformationPanelVisible, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
         >
    <TextBlock 
            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            Text="{Binding InformationPanelText}"
        />
 </Border>
```

Part of my Code from ViewModel:

```
public bool IsInformationPanelVisible
{
   get
   {
       return this._isInformationPanelVisible;
   }
   set
   {
       if (this._isInformationPanelVisible == value)
       {
            return;
       }

       this._isInformationPanelVisible = value;

       if (this._isInformationPanelVisible)
       {
           new Timer((state) => 
           {
                this.IsInformationPanelVisible = false;         
           }, null, 3000, 0);
       }

       DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
       {
           RaisePropertyChanged("IsInformationPanelVisible");
       });
   }
}
```

My question is: Why it does not work in the case that user touches the display and moves the map?

It is not possible to debug it.

I underwent tests and it seems that Timer CallBack is not fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. The biggest one is a bug in your timer callback lambda - you don't raise the `PropertyChanged` event after three seconds you raise it immediately. You should have the RaisePropertyChanged call inside your lambda (giving a lambda inside a lambda!):

```
   if (this._isInformationPanelVisible)
   {
       new Timer((state) => 
       {
            this.IsInformationPanelVisible = false;        
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsInformationPanelVisible");
            });       
       }, null, 3000, 0);
   }
```

Also, the Timer callback (lambda) will run on a background thread which is at lower priority than the UI thread - this is another reason why your update may not be firing.

Of course if you use a `DispatcherTimer` you won't have either of these problems - it always runs on the UI thread.